# Meteor 1.3.1 and delay simulation

Tags: meteor, delay, meteor-publications

I'm trying to add `Meteor._sleepForMs(2000);` or even `Meteor._sleepForMs(20000);` to my publication and nothing happens.

How I can add delay??

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: forgot remove autopublish.... `Meteor._sleepForMs(2000);` works fine without autopublish